# Spring Security Unauthorized after short connection cut

Tags: spring-security, database-connection, access-denied

I'm working on an application using Spring Security and Oracle & Cassandra as database.
Client authentication works fine until a short database outage occurs, then the application continues to return access denied, even after the databases are available again.
The application needs to be restarted to stop throwing access denied to clients...
This happens on methods annotated with

```
    @PostAuthorize("hasPermission(returnObject?.customer,'read')")
```

I'm wondering if loss of connections impact somehow spring security context, in a irreversible way ?

I know I'm not providing much information, but I'm posting this in case someone have an idea why a short loss of connection pushes the application into endless access denied.

The error message each time is :

```
Access is denied org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
at org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedPostInvocationAdvice.after(ExpressionBasedPostInvocationAdvice.java:62)
at org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PostInvocationAdviceProvider.decide(PostInvocationAdviceProvider.java:41)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AfterInvocationProviderManager.decide(AfterInvocationProviderManager.java:81)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.afterInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:316)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:73)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
```

Regards,

Comment: I don't think that this has much to do with Spring Security. I guess your database driver has a problem. Show your logs. You have to change log cofiguration to `DEBUG` for at least Spring Security.

Comment: This is what I expect to do in production. We are in spring-security-core 4.0.0, i updated the post with error message

Comment: Your have to show DEBUB log, too. The error is not enough.